# startxfce4 in lxc container got error

Tags: linux, lxc

I want to launch GUI in my lxc container. The container I used ubuntu 14.04 with xfce4.

```
ubuntu@test1:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri$ startxfce4
[1459480.127] 
X.Org X Server 1.15.1
Release Date: 2014-04-13
[1459480.127] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[1459480.127] Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-76-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[1459480.127] Current Operating System: Linux test1 3.13.0-24-generic #46-
Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64
[1459480.127] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-
generic root=UUID=ff746abe-8309-4531-9677-c9291ae0557e ro
[1459480.127] Build Date: 12 February 2015  02:49:29PM
[1459480.127] xorg-server 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2.7 (For technical support please 
see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
...
...
[1459480.154]   ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[1459480.154] (II) CIRRUS: driver for Cirrus chipsets: CLGD5430, CLGD5434-4, CLGD5434-8,
    CLGD5436, CLGD5446, CLGD5480, CL-GD5462, CL-GD5464, CL-GD5464BD,
    CL-GD5465, CL-GD7548, CL-GD7555, CL-GD7556
[1459480.154] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[1459480.154] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[1459480.154] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[1459480.154] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[1459480.154] (EE) xf86OpenConsole: Cannot open /dev/tty0 (No such file or directory)
[1459480.154] (EE) 
[1459480.154] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[1459480.154] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[1459480.154] (EE)
```

I can connect to my container with VNC. But what I need is start GUI directly. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

There was a thread related to this problem on StackOverflow that is closed now. In that thread they suggested to do the following command to start X:

`startx -- :1`

Be aware that you need to ensure that `dev/tty0` exists inside your container first and if the above doesn't help please send the last lines of logs available in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` for further analysis.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I got the same error with this command. /dev/tty0 exist inside my container.